# Homepage constantly refreshes after adding Facebook Login button

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, firefox

I just added the Facebook login button to my site and it refreshes the page every second.

This happens on FF but not Chrome or IE.

Here is the home page: http://comehike.com/

Any idea why this might be happening?

Here is a test page that has the problem: http://www.comehike.com/index_alex.php

Comment: Doesn't refresh on Ubuntu 11.04 (using Firefox 5.x)

Comment: @David I have windows 7 and FF 5

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `FB.login()` called before calling `FB.init()`

Comment: After swapping them, the same behavior persists.

Comment: Sorry I gotta leave work. If you're still having issues this evening I'll be back on. Peace!

Comment: @Thanks - I posted the problematic code and I reverted to the working version on the live site.